# How to include loop inside transection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

i have the following code

```
 List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> localList2 = [] ; // inside list i have 5 docs 
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
    for (var element in localList2) {
      DocumentReference userDoc= FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(element.get('userId'));
      DocumentSnapshot chick = await transaction.get(userDoc);
      if(chick.exists){
        transaction.update(element.get('targetDocRef'),{
          'fieldValue': 'value',
        });
      }
    }
  }).then((value){
    log.log('done');
  }).catchError((error){
    log.log(error.toString());
  });
```

when i run it i got the following error message

> Transactions require all reads to be executed before all writes.

however i am not seeing any write task before read .

so i tried to use the whole transection into loop and this working fine but in my case i need it to chick result and write at once for whole docs .

how could i make it done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be misunderstanding the error message.  It's saying that **all** reads must happen before **all** writes.  If there is more that one iteration of your loop, on the second iteration, the read for that iteration will happen after the first write.  That means not **all** of your reads are happening before **all** of the writes.

Instead, have one loop that just reads all necessary documents, then after that, another loop that just writes all necessary documents.

Comment: thanks .. kindly if you show me how to use 2 loop i will be thankful to you . i am really struggling with that

Comment: That's a new question - please post it separately.

Comment: thanks , i already posted new one . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105579/how-can-i-read-first-then-perform-write-in-two-loop-into-transection