# how can i read first then perform write in two loop into transection

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have asked question in the following link

[How to include loop inside transection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105066/how-to-include-loop-inside-transection/76105226?noredirect=1#comment134218369_76105226)

it is about error message says

```
Transactions require all reads to be executed before all writes.
```

and that was my code

```
List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> localList2 = [] ; // inside list i have 5 docs 
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
    for (var element in localList2) {
      DocumentReference userDoc= FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(element.get('userId'));
      DocumentSnapshot chick = await transaction.get(userDoc);
      if(chick.exists){
        transaction.update(element.get('targetDocRef'),{
          'fieldValue': 'value',
        });
      }
    }
  }).then((value){
    log.log('done');
  }).catchError((error){
    log.log(error.toString());
  });
```

and i got answer **from Doug Stevenson**

> I think you might be misunderstanding the error message. It's saying
> that all reads must happen before all writes. If there is more that
> one iteration of your loop, on the second iteration, the read for that
> iteration will happen after the first write. That means not all of
> your reads are happening before all of the writes.
>
> Instead, have one loop that just reads all necessary documents, then
> after that, another loop that just writes all necessary documents.

but how could i make two loops in correct way  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, I guess:

```
List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> localList2 = [];
Map<QueryDocumentSnapshot, DocumentSnapshot> docs = {};
FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
  for (var element in localList2) {
    DocumentReference userDoc= FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(element.get('userId'));
    DocumentSnapshot chick = await transaction.get(userDoc);
    docs[element] = chick; //  store the document mapping for later
  }
  for (var entry in docs.entries) { 
    if (entry.value.exists) { //  entry.value is chick from above
      transaction.update(entry.key.get('targetDocRef'), { //  entry.key is element from above
        'fieldValue': 'value',
      });
    }
  })
}).then((value){
  log.log('done');
}).catchError((error){
  log.log(error.toString());
});
```

So the first loop only gets the documents and stores references to them, while the second loop then updates all documents that you got.

Comment: thank now i understand . but i think you forgot to add another list to store element.get('targetDocRef'),{ //  .. because this element also come from loop

Comment: edit : it give me new error message .. PlatformException(firebase_firestore, Document version changed between two reads., {code: aborted, message: The operation was aborted, typically due to a concurrency issue like transaction aborts, etc.}, null)

Comment: Good to hear that my explanation helped you understand. --- If you get an error while trying to make it work, it's a good moment to edit your question to show what [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you ended up with - and the complete error message and stack trace.

Comment: after hard test i find out the issue occur by repeating the same doc chick in loop . sometimes gives error sometimes work . but with preventing the duplicated chick the error disappear forever . thanks a gain Frank . without your example i am nothing